# Concat string and byte in http header

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to upload a zip by post request. To do this I need to send string and byte data.

Ok the problem is the binary encoding still. The original zip encoding first line is `PK........,Q?E?;`, where as the uploaded copy is `PK........,Q.E.;` The original has `?` whereas the copy converts them to `.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Convert it to a string:

```powershell
[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([byte]$file)
```

#### More readable:

```powershell
$byteArray = [byte]$file
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII
$stringContents = $enc.GetString($byteArray)
```

You can use other encodings if the content of the file is actually in Unicode or some other encoding.

To see the other encodings:

```powershell
[System.Text.Encoding] | Get-Member -Type Properties -Static
```

## Edit based on comment:

I misunderstood your question. You are concerned that the bytes are being converted to the ASCII representation of the byte's numerical value.

This is not actually what is happening. When you use `Write-Host`, *it is then* that the conversion is happening, for display purposes only.

The values in the byte array are the raw binary data.

## Edit based on your edit:

You are embedding the byte array `$bytes` in another string. This is implicitly converting it to a display-able format, which is not what you want.

`$bytes` does contain the raw data. In this case, what you want is for each byte to be placed directly in the string as is. You should try using the first solution I posted, and then embed `$stringContents` instead of `$bytes` in `$parameters`. I think this will do what you are hoping for.

Don't confuse what's printed on the screen when you display a string with what it actually contains. Although a `[String]` object can be more complex, at its simplest a string *is* an array of bytes. In C for example, you don't declare strings, you declare an array of `char` (which is usually a byte).

I urge you to try the method whereby you convert it to a string and comment if it's not working.

Comment: I don't want a string, I want to get the raw binary data. I'm trying to post binary data, but I believe it's getting converted to ascii behind the scenes. Which corrupts the upload.

Comment: Have a look at my edit. I think that in fact you have nothing to worry about. If you're having a specific problem using the byte array you should edit your question and include that code.

Comment: I just realized you did edit the question, but I don't get notified about that. I've edited my answer again in response.

Comment: I tried that and it was still accepting it as ascii. Part of me is confused by this because I explicitly set Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary. So either either powershell conversion, the server isn't accepting the headers correctly, or something is wrong with my post formatting. I'm trying to narrow it down.

Comment: Post more code, show how you're making the request, etc. If you can also give output from the remote server, that could be helpful. If possible, try to use something that captures both sides of the HTTP calls like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler).

Comment: It seems like the binary data invalidates the http header.